Is it possible to edit the line between the body and footnotes in google docs using GAS?
By default, Google docs inserts a divider line between the body and footnotes. It's impossible to edit or change that using the standard menus. Does anyone know if it can be edited or eliminated using apps script?

I'm no expert, but a quick glance through the methods and attributes in the relevant classes in the GAS reference, and a quick DuckDuckGo search both suggest that it's not possible; see this answer.

Thanks. That's my judgment so far as well. It is what it is. I'm always amazed by how much google docs ... and also doesn't ... do.
